# Running an .exe via the shell command - program blinks open and close

Tags: vba, shell, excel

So, I have a problem while trying to open an .exe file via my vba. Basically I want to open the exe give it a few key strokes to get an output and then use that output.

However whenever I use the SHELL function to open the exe it just blinks open and closed on the screen, or given some of the focus options will just give me the your program crashed notification.

The code I am using is simple

```
Sub Run_exe()
Shell ThisWorkbook.Path & "\mlt932w.exe", vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

I am aware that this could be an issue with the program and nothing to do with vba, I was just wondering if anyone has come up against a similar issue and was able to solve it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If your .exe is a script (i.e. batch script), try to add some sort of PAUSE to it.  Chances are the error comes from the .exe and usually a syntax error.  Adding pause will let you know what's wrong

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Alex - SO my .exe is a 3rd party program which I have no control over, I'm just creating an input file for it wanting to run it to get the output file (in txt format) and do some post processing. I am afraid that it may just be an issue with the program. I know it can be opened via python and a similar task completed however it doesn't want to work for me in vba.

Answer (score 0):

Since the application you are running may be exiting the controlling terminal (cmd), I think you need to run this is in a wrapper bat file which launches another `cmd` instance to execute the program.

Create a start_app.bat (in `ThisWorkbook.Path`) file containing:

```
@echo off
cmd /c %0\..\mlt932w.exe
pause
```

Then try launching the `.bat` file from VBA:

```
Sub Run_exe()
Shell ThisWorkbook.Path & "\start_app.bat", vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Both run the program but with the same problems as if I had ran it with my code. appears and disappears in a short period of time

Comment: @DarrenFillis I updated the answer to use a wrapper .bat file, which I think will fix your problem.

Comment: @DarrenFillis Basically, without using a wrapper file, it appears an `exit` call propagates up `cmd /c ..` calls.

Comment: so Something weird happens when I try and run it this way via vba. Noting it runs fine when I just click on the .bat file I just created. When i run it via VBA the CMD window shows "'mlt932w.exe' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @DarrenFillis I edited "start_app.bat" contents to use an absolute path to the mlt932w.exe file.

Comment: @ myninjaname Ok, so yea I guess I am just bad at VBA ... I managed to get it working now, letting me know that it wasn't able to pick up the file as an executable lead me to realize I hadn't actually defined the current directory. Whenever I did that it worked fine, so I guess what i thought the problem was all along wasn't the problem. Again thanks a lot for the help and sorry for being such an idot.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code below to open a .exe file but it doesn't work.

```
Sub testF2()

Dim Program As Integer
Program = Shell(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Tool\missra\missra.bat", vbMaximizedFocus)
AppActivate (Program)

End Sub
```